# MotionEvent.ACTION_UP not activated in onTouchEvent

Tags: java, android

I can't get an event to trigger when the user stops pressing on the view.

In my object that extends `SurfaceView` and implements `SurfaceHolder.Callback` I have declared an object called `leftButton` which handles (you guessed it) the button to move left. I want the variable `leftButton.isDown` to be `true` when the button is being pressed and `false` at all other times. When the button is pressed `"Pressed Down"` appears in logs and the value of `leftButton.isDown` is set to `true`, but when it's released the value doesn't change and nothing appears in logs. My understanding is that when the button is released `event.getAction()` should be equal to `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`. Why is this not working

```java
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();


        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (x >= 100 && x < 400
                        && y >= 1700 && y < 3600) {

                    leftButton.isDown = true;
                    Log.d("Touch Event", "Pressed Down");
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                leftButton.isDown = false;
                Log.d("Touch Event", "Released");
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return true in your:

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
```

otherwise android will not send any further events to your listener.

Comment: thank you, it worked. I'll also add for any person in the future with the same problem who finds this comment that it needs to be `return true;`